# How can get text box value from into the table cell?

Tags: jquery

I have this html code:

```
<table style="width:100%;border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:5em;" id="DeputyForce">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <img src="/Assistance/MyIm.jpg" />
      <br/> AA
      <br/> AAAA
      <input type="text" class="DeputyID" value=1 />
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <img src="/Content/Image/mrNoProfileLogo.png" />
      <br/> BBB
      <br/> BBBBB
      <input type="text" class="DeputyID" value=2 />
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

I try write jquery code for this purpose,when user click on the cell show the `DeputyID`   value,for that purpose write this jquery code:

```
$('#DeputyForce tr td').click(function () {
    alert($(this).siblings('.DeputyID').val());
});
```

but show me undefined message,how can i solve that problem?thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.DeputyID` is `children()` not `siblings()`

```js
$('#DeputyForce tr td').click(function() {
  alert($(this).children('.DeputyID').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%;border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:5em;" id="DeputyForce">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <img src="/Assistance/MyIm.jpg" />
      <br/> AA
      <br/> AAAA
      <input type="text" class="DeputyID" value=1 />
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <img src="/Content/Image/mrNoProfileLogo.png" />
      <br/> BBB
      <br/> BBBBB
      <input type="text" class="DeputyID" value=2 />
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please wait to test your solution

Comment: @behzadrazza It's been more than 9 minutes

Comment: @Barmar Thanks.